# Getting error message (if value is not None and not value.has_key() )

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to save Event. But it does not work. Will you please help? thanks alot

```
query = []
query = Identity.all().filter('name =', 'k').fetch(1)
if query:
  for q in query:
    event_id = q.key().id()

    Event(description=description, identity=event_id)
```

Event Model

```
class Event(search.SearchableModel):
   description = db.TextProperty(required=True)
   identity = db.ReferenceProperty(Identity)
```

Getting error message >

```
if value is not None and not value.has_key():
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assigning the id of the object into a ReferenceProeprty, this is wrong.
Your code should look something like this:

```
query = Identity.all().filter('name =', 'k').get()
if query:
    Event(description=description, identity=q)
```

Also instead of having your own name attribute you use use the buitin key_name attribute that each Model has, its faster and cheaper.

```
query = Identity.get_by_key_name(k)
if query:
    Event(description=description, identity=q)
```